# Can raus sound like räusch in some German dialects?

Tags: dialect

I was on a train in the stretch between Wiesbaden and Basel the other day and a fellow was asking me for help in assisting a passenger in a wheelchair to disembark at the next stop.

I had trouble understanding this, because he kept saying something about noise.  I kept hearing the sound *räusch*, which made me think he was saying *Geräusch*, and I couldn't make head or tail of his sentence.

Finally, in retrospect, I wondered if he might have been saying *raus*.

Is there a region of Germany where the word *raus* can come out sounding like *räusch*?

If not, what else might he have been saying that would have had something to do with helping a passenger in a wheelchair to leave a train?

Comment: Maybe you heard **Rollstuhl** which may in fact be pronounced **räusch tu**.

Comment: @Janka If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.  It seems more likely than the other answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word **Rollstuhl** (wheelchair) can be heard as **räusch tu**, especially is south-west dialects.

Answer (score 1):

As this was the South West of Germany, it is quite possible that you encountered e.g. Swabian or Allemannian dialect. "Naus" is a common form of saying "raus" (hinaus) there.

In Swabian dialect it would not be uncommon to say something like

> Keetsch mr mol hälfa deen nauszomhäaba?

(Könntest du mir mal helfen, diesen [Herrn] hinauszutragen?)

Other dialects could also be involved. The South West is rich of strong dialects.

Comment: Kosch mer mol mei radradra?

Comment: Abr erscht kommsch her d'abradradra!

Comment: Interessant. Mir  fehlt allerdings die Phantasie, wo sich im Beispielsatz das vom OP genannte *räusch* verbergen soll. Könntest du das irgendwie markieren?